# MS Access 64 bit the connection to Visual Foxpro

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016, visual-foxpro

After switching from Office 365 32 bit to Office 64 bit the connection to Visual Foxpro does not work anymore.

So with :
*"Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider; Data Source=D:ACCESSImport; ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER; TableType=ADS_VFP;"*

and

*Dim AdsGetCustRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set AdsGetCustRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
AdsGetCustRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM TABLE", objcon, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText*

Actually the access is possible. However with error messages from the Advantage Client Engine.

"exception code was generated when calling the user supplied callbackfuntion . it is being disabled"

Maybe someone can help me.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you also need to update  the ODBC driver

Answer (score 0):

Advantage Database has both a 32- and 64-bit drivers, make sure you have correct version.  If you are not seeing the

```
ACE64.dll
ADSLOC64.dll
ADSOLEDB64.dll
AICU64.dll
AXCWS64.dll
```

That is probably why.

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback. I use adsoledb_x86_64.exe Version 11.10.24.0
In the Folder: C:\Program Files\Advantage 11.10\OLEDB
ace64.dll, adscollate.adm, adscollate.adt, adsloc64.dll, adslocal.cfg, adslocal_org.cfg, adsoledb64.dll, aicu64.dll, ansi.chr, axcws64.dll, extend.chr, icudt40l.dat, license.txt