# How MS Access 64 bit import or link from Visual FoxPro database?

Tags: vba, ms-access, visual-foxpro

before I use MS Access 2010 32 bit link to Visual FoxPro through ODBC driver. after I upgrade to MS Access 2016 64 bit. the ODBC driver does not show Visual FoxPro databases. and Access cannot connect to VFP. anyone can advise?

Comment: Need a 64-bit driver? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621090/ms-access-64-bit-the-connection-to-visual-foxpro

Answer (score 2):

There never was nor is a x64 bit version of FoxPro. As a result, if you want to consume VFP files? Then your .net project has to remain x32 bits.

And same goes for using the VFP odbc driver. They are x32 bits only, and thus your .net software, or in this case ms-access software MUST remain as the x32 bit version.

Foxpro is x32 bit technology only - and thus any software that interacts or is to consume VFP data also must remain as x32 bits.

You can't use the x64 bit version of Access - it will not work with x32 bit software.

Comment: Thanks Albert. So I have to remove MS office 64 bit and reinstall 34 bit instead.

Comment: Yes, not much choice you have. You can install a different or previous version of access and you can with efforts install both x32 and x64 access if they are different office versions. But regardless. You have to use x32 access since FoxPro is x32